# C variable declarations

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void){
    char c1[], c2[];
    c1 = "hello";
    c2 = "world";
    printf("%s %s", c1, c2);
    return 0;
}
```

What exactly makes it that I cannot use 'char c1[], c2[]'? I have some knowledge in Java and I find C syntax to be rather familiar with it but clearly somethings do not work.

Is there also any reason why char is declared as char variable[] instead of char[] variable? It seems to make more sense like this (Java notation)

Comment: I never use c for long time but if I remember array must defined length

Comment: you write `c[2] = 'x';` and not `[2]c = 'x';`, so you write `char c[3];` and not `char[3] c;` .

Comment: `char c1[]` - so how many characters do you expect c1 to hold? In C, this makes c1 an array, *not* a reference to an array like it does in Java.

Comment: Just forget about Java and study a beginner-level book in C.

Comment: regarding this kind of expression: `char c1[]`,  An array in C, must be either declared with a specific length or initialized with a char string.  I.E. either: `char c1[20];`   or `char c1[] = "hello ";`.   Strings can only be copied char by char or using a function like: `strcpy()`   Only at variable initialization can a char array be set using `=`.

Comment: For ease of readability and understanding by us humans: 1) use meaningful variable names.  A variable name should indicate content or usage (or both).  2) suggest inserting appropriate white space, for readability.

Comment: this is assignment: `char c1[20]; ....  strcpy( c1, "hello" );`   This is initialization: `char c1[] = "hello";

Answer (score 6):

This:

```
char c1[]
```

Means "An array of characters with unknown length."  You can't create arrays of unknown length, though you can take them as parameters to a function, as in:

```
void foo(char c1[])
```

You can also create them if the length is known implicitly, as in:

```
char c1[] = "hello"; // size is 6, including null terminator
```

And as for this:

> Is there also any reason why char is declared as char variable[] instead of char[] variable?

It has always been like this.  I'm sure C programmers feel the Java way doesn't make sense too.  Decisions made in language syntax 40 years ago are not usefully debated today.

Comment: But why is it in the case that char c1[] = "hello"; it is able to figure it out on its own whilst if you have more than one character array it suddenly needs the direct length? What if I wanted to input a giant string of text that I didnt know the length for?

Comment: Specifically, it says "make me an array of unknown length on the stack". Which makes no sense. In Java it means "make me a pointer to an array on the stack", this is because of Java's concept of 'value type' and 'reference type'.

Comment: I dont understand... in the code above if I removed c2 altogether the code works fine... yet I didnt declare the size of the array. Why does this work?

Comment: Technically OP's array would gain an implicit size in the first assignment. Hypothetically the compiler could attempt to find a first assignment, so I think a little bit more needs to be explained. "hello" is known at compile time after all.

Answer (score 1):

That code precisely speaking is not declarations, it's definitions. And in C, you cannot define arrays leaving the length empty, you can either specify it explicitly:

```
char c1[6] = "hello";
```

or you can do it implicitly:

```
char c1[] = "hello";
```

If the length of the array is only known in running time, use allocated arrays:

```
size_t n = <calculate the size needed>;
char *c1 = malloc(n);
```

But for declarations, you can do external declarations like this:

```
extern char c1[];
```

Comment: So let us say id want to declare a string array that contains well over 1000 characters, how would I know what to input?

Comment: @Wjk just do `char c[1000];`?

Comment: @Wjk If the size is not known at developing time and it is calculated in runtime, you need to use dynamic allocation: `size_t n = get_size(); char *c1 = malloc(n);`

Comment: Or you could simply do `char c1[n]`.

Comment: @Lundin Yes, that will also do.

Comment: @Lundin It's a size he doesn't know.

Comment: @MillieSmith So...? If he doesn't know it, he will obviously have to find out about it before declaring the array. Prompt the user for it etc.

Comment: @Lundin Ok, then he can't use the `char c1[n]` syntax.

Comment: @MillieSmith Of course he can, it is a VLA. I would guess that your C knowledge is more than 17 years outdated.

Comment: @Lundin Ok well it became optional in C11, and Visual Studio apparently doesn't support it. A little different than "this can be done", but thanks nonetheless. I did not know about VLAs.

Comment: @MillieSmith Visual Studio is not a conforming C compiler. If you are lucky, it might conform to some C++ standard, but I very much doubt it

Comment: @Lundin I know, but it can't be thrown out of the equation. It's used a lot. You might be in a gcc world of conformity, but not everyone is.

Comment: @Lundin Also, it does conform to quite a bit of the C++11 and C++14 standards iirc.